# processing payments with an ActionScript based shopping cart

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, adobe, e-commerce, credit-card

I was approached by an old client about making a boutique web site that showcases one product, and lets the user make a purchase. I wanted to make the site in flash, but I havent had any luck figuring out how to process the payments with a service such as Authorize.net (securely, too). Any advice would be much appreciated.

-Evan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you'll have to use a server-side language as well.  here's the minimum you need using PHP and cURL:  http://upshots.org/?p=63

once that's in place, you send the HTTP request like you would any other.  create a URLVariables object, attach your REQUEST variables to it, add that object as the data property of a URLRequest object, which is fed to a URLLoader object to be sent.